# Looking for alternative to Selenium for scraping multiple pages

Tags: python, pandas, performance, selenium, beautifulsoup

I get the desired results but I think some the code could be improved. It's currently quite slow and error prone when scraping multiple pages in a row. The code below scrapes 5 features for 42 vehicles (21 per page). I'm scraping a total of 18 features (other 13 features are not shown here) for these two pages but it takes too long considering I wish to scrape a total of 29 pages.

In order to see the vehicle price you need to log in which is why I'm using Selenium as shown in the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell #optional

# Change cell settings (optional)
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
pd.options.display.max_rows = 100
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 100
pd.options.display.max_columns = None

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#driver.maximize_window() #optional

# Log in and search  
urls = ["https://www.example.com/"]

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name("dropdown-toggle")[0].click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_elements_by_name('email')[0].send_keys("arjenvgeffen@hotmail.com")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_elements_by_name("submit")[0].click()
    time.sleep(2)

    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('SEARCH')
    time.sleep(1)
    link.click()
    time.sleep(2)

    driver.find_elements_by_name("searchScope")[0].send_keys('ALL PAST')
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_elements_by_name("searchMake")[0].send_keys('PLYMOUTH')
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_elements_by_name('searchModel')[0].send_keys('Cuda')
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_elements_by_name('searchYearStart')[0].send_keys("1970")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_elements_by_name('searchYearEnd')[0].send_keys("1971")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[. = 'Search']").click()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The code below scrapes the vehicle title (year_make_model_type), price (which you can only see after loggin in above with email) and the page urls. The page_urls will be used in the next step to scrape information per product page. This takes too long when scraping 29 pages and it tends to skip/get stuck. Any improvement here is much appreciated!

```
# Scrape two pages (these two variables can be scraped without being on the vehicle page)
i = 0
x = 1
year_make_model_type = []
price = []

while True:
    for i in range(0,1):
        time.sleep(2)
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        time.sleep(2)
        urls = [x.get('href') for x in soup.findAll("a", class_ = "lot-title")]
        time.sleep(2)
        mystring = 'https://www.example.com'
        page_urls = [mystring + s for s in urls]
        time.sleep(2)
        for y in soup.find_all("a", class_ = ("lot-title")):
            year_make_model_type.append(y.text)
        time.sleep(2)
        for p in soup.find_all("span", class_ = ("lot-price")):
            price.append(re.sub("[\$\,]", "", p.text))
        time.sleep(2)    
        i +=1 
        for x in range(2,3):
            time.sleep(5)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="/search/page/%d/"]' % (x,)).click()
            time.sleep(5)
            html = driver.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
            time.sleep(2)
            page_products_urls = [x.get('href') for x in soup.findAll("a", class_ = "lot-title")]
            time.sleep(2)
            mystring = 'https://www.example.com'
            page_products_urls2 = [mystring + s for s in page_products_urls]
            page_urls.extend(page_products_urls2)
            time.sleep(2)
            for y in soup.find_all("a", class_ = ("lot-title")):
                year_make_model_type.append(y.text)
            time.sleep(2)
            for p in soup.find_all("span", class_ = ("lot-price")):
                price.append(re.sub("[\$\,]", "", p.text))
            time.sleep(2)  
            x += 1
    if x == 2:
        break
    else:
        break

len(page_urls) #42
len(set(page_urls)) #42
len(price) #42
len(set(price)) #36
len(year_make_model_type) #42
len(set(year_make_model_type)) #13

# If you need to go back to the first page 
#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="/search/page/1/"]').click()

# Create df
scraped_data = pd.DataFrame({'url': page_urls, 'year_make_model_type': year_make_model_type, 'price':price})
scraped_data['price'] = scraped_data['price'].replace('', np.NaN)
scraped_data['price'] = scraped_data['price'].astype(float)
scraped_data.shape
scraped_data.head()

#driver.quit()
```

This last bit of code scrapes the highlights and flag_group per vehicle from its product page.

```
# Create additional features per product url (have to click on product to be able to scrape these features)
def getAndParseURL(url):
    result = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
    return(soup)

highlights = []
flag_group = []

# Add features per vehicle
for url in page_urls:

    # Vehicle highlights
    highlights1 = []
    soup = getAndParseURL(url)
    if not soup.find("ul", class_ = "lot-highlights hidden-print"): 
        highlights1.append(np.NaN)
    else:
        hl = soup.find("ul", class_ = "lot-highlights hidden-print").text.strip()
        hl = hl.replace("\n", ", ").strip()
        highlights1.append(hl)

    highlights.extend(highlights1)

    # Vehicle flag_group
    attraction = []
    soup = getAndParseURL(url)
    flag = soup.find(class_=["flag flag-main","flag flag-star", "flag flag-feature"])
    if flag:
        attraction.append(flag.contents[0])
    else:
        attraction.append(np.NaN)

    flag_group.extend(attraction)

# Assign new features to existing df
scraped_data = scraped_data.assign(**{'highlights': highlights, 'flag_group': flag_group})#, 'reserve': reserve})
scraped_data.shape
scraped_data.head()
```

Let me know/show me wherever you think the code above can be improved. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: I would start by refactoring the code into smaller functions, each one with a single responsibility well stated in the Docstring. So one  for the login (if you really need to login), one that opens the URL and returns the soup object, a general parser function broken down into smaller helpers. If you want it go faster you could consider using multiprocessing, although you need to take into account that automated browser scrapers are generally slow and unreliable. Another option if speed is an issue is to use Scrapy/Splash, which will handle the concurrency for you in a quite robust way.

Comment: Thanks NomadMonad I will look into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **Really** **Really** don't need all this very long code at all.

You don't need even `selenium`.

You don't need to keep repeat your code and all this stuff.

Below should achieve your goal easily!

> Note: I've **scraped** only the first 3 pages, You can increase the loop for your desired target.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from prettytable import PrettyTable

data = {
    "searchScope": "past",
    "searchText": "PLYMOUTH",
    "searchMake": "Plymouth",
    "searchModel": "Cuda",
    "searchYearStart": "1970",
    "searchYearEnd": "1971",
    "submit": ""
}

headers = {
    "Referer": "https://www.mecum.com",
}

login = {"email": "arjenvgeffen@hotmail.com"}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.post(
            "https://www.mecum.com/includes/login-action.cfm", data=login)
        p = PrettyTable()
        p.field_names = ["Name", "Url", "Price"]
        for item in range(1, 4):
            r = req.post(url.format(item), data=data, headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            target = soup.select("div.lot")
            for tar in target:
                price = tar.span.text if tar.span.text else "N/A"

                hint = tar.select_one("a.lot-title")
                p.add_row(
                    [hint.text, f"{url[:21]}{hint['href']}", price])
        print(p)


main("https://www.mecum.com/search/page/{}/")
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|                           Name                           |                                             Url                                              |  Price   |
+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|                   1936 Plymouth  Coupe                   |                https://www.mecum.com/lots/HA0420-412309/1936-plymouth-coupe/                 |   N/A    |
|               1937 Plymouth Deluxe Pickup                |            https://www.mecum.com/lots/HA0420-412385/1937-plymouth-deluxe-pickup/             |   N/A    |
|                1951 Plymouth  Convertible                |             https://www.mecum.com/lots/HA0420-412744/1951-plymouth-convertible/              |   N/A    |
|                1968 Plymouth Road Runner                 |             https://www.mecum.com/lots/HA0420-412874/1968-plymouth-road-runner/              |   N/A    |
|                    1970 Plymouth Cuda                    |                 https://www.mecum.com/lots/HA0420-413047/1970-plymouth-cuda/                 |   N/A    |
|              1971 Plymouth Cuda Convertible              |           https://www.mecum.com/lots/HA0420-413138/1971-plymouth-cuda-convertible/           |   N/A    |
|                1968 Plymouth Road Runner                 |             https://www.mecum.com/lots/HA0420-427812/1968-plymouth-road-runner/              |   N/A    |
|                1969 Plymouth Road Runner                 |             https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-404226/1969-plymouth-road-runner/              | $19,250  |
|             1973 Plymouth Duster Police Car              |          https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-404232/1973-plymouth-duster-police-car/           | $18,700  |
|       1963 Plymouth Valiant Signet 200 Convertible       |    https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-404250/1963-plymouth-valiant-signet-200-convertible/    |  $3,850  |
|                   1946 Plymouth  Taxi                    |                 https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-404267/1946-plymouth-taxi/                 |  $3,300  |
|                    1969 Plymouth GTX                     |                 https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-404449/1969-plymouth-gtx/                  | $25,000  |
|                  1999 Plymouth Prowler                   |               https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-404457/1999-plymouth-prowler/                | $20,000  |
|        1967 Plymouth Barracuda Formula S Fastback        |     https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-404478/1967-plymouth-barracuda-formula-s-fastback/     | $33,000  |
|              1970 Plymouth Cuda Convertible              |           https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-404626/1970-plymouth-cuda-convertible/           | $51,700  |
|                    1967 Plymouth GTX                     |                 https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-404634/1967-plymouth-gtx/                  | $31,350  |
|               1970 Plymouth Cuda Resto Mod               |            https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-404636/1970-plymouth-cuda-resto-mod/            | $50,000  |
|                1969 Plymouth Road Runner                 |             https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-404656/1969-plymouth-road-runner/              | $34,100  |
|                    1970 Plymouth Cuda                    |                 https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-404858/1970-plymouth-cuda/                 | $70,000  |
|                 1970 Plymouth Superbird                  |              https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-404866/1970-plymouth-superbird/               | $143,000 |
|           1967 Plymouth Satellite Convertible            |        https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-404883/1967-plymouth-satellite-convertible/         | $30,800  |
|                  1970 Plymouth AAR Cuda                  |               https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-404897/1970-plymouth-aar-cuda/               | $71,500  |
|            1967 Plymouth Barracuda Resto Mod             |         https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-404918/1967-plymouth-barracuda-resto-mod/          | $60,500  |
|              1969 Plymouth GTX Convertible               |           https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-404950/1969-plymouth-gtx-convertible/            | $42,000  |
|                 1959 Plymouth Sport Fury                 |              https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-404972/1959-plymouth-sport-fury/              | $30,000  |
|                 1965 Plymouth Barracuda                  |              https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-405120/1965-plymouth-barracuda/               | $22,000  |
|                 1970 Plymouth Hemi Cuda                  |              https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-405220/1970-plymouth-hemi-cuda/               | $150,700 |
|                 1970 Plymouth Superbird                  |              https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-405229/1970-plymouth-superbird/               | $115,000 |
|                    1970 Plymouth Cuda                    |                 https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-405236/1970-plymouth-cuda/                 | $52,500  |
|                 1970 Plymouth Hemi Cuda                  |              https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-405266/1970-plymouth-hemi-cuda/               | $130,000 |
|              1968 Plymouth Hemi Road Runner              |           https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-405267/1968-plymouth-hemi-road-runner/           | $70,000  |
|              1969 Plymouth Hemi Road Runner              |           https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-405286/1969-plymouth-hemi-road-runner/           | $62,000  |
|                1969 Plymouth Road Runner                 |             https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-405304/1969-plymouth-road-runner/              | $120,000 |
|           1959 Plymouth Sport Fury Convertible           |        https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-405321/1959-plymouth-sport-fury-convertible/        | $70,000  |
|               1973 Plymouth Cuda Resto Mod               |            https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-405340/1973-plymouth-cuda-resto-mod/            | $75,000  |
|        1969 Plymouth Sport Satellite Convertible         |     https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-405384/1969-plymouth-sport-satellite-convertible/      | $37,400  |
|                  1970 Plymouth AAR Cuda                  |               https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-405385/1970-plymouth-aar-cuda/               | $55,000  |
|                1969 Plymouth Road Runner                 |             https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-423532/1969-plymouth-road-runner/              | $60,500  |
|                 1970 Plymouth Hemi Cuda                  |              https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-423534/1970-plymouth-hemi-cuda/               | $93,500  |
|              1968 Plymouth Hemi Road Runner              |           https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-423535/1968-plymouth-hemi-road-runner/           | $66,000  |
|                    1970 Plymouth Cuda                    |                 https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-423545/1970-plymouth-cuda/                 | $60,000  |
|  1940s-50s Desoto Plymouth Double-Sided Porcelain 45x42  |  https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-424465/1940s-50s-desoto-plymouth-double-sided-porcelain/  |  $2,950  |
|  1940s-50s Dodge Plymouth Double-Sided Porcelain 42-in   |  https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-424468/1940s-50s-dodge-plymouth-double-sided-porcelain/   |  $5,900  |
| 1940s-50s Chrysler Plymouth Double-Sided Porcelain 42-in | https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-424471/1940s-50s-chrysler-plymouth-double-sided-porcelain/ |  $3,776  |
|                1969 Plymouth Road Runner                 |             https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-424624/1969-plymouth-road-runner/              | $59,400  |
|           1965 Plymouth Sport Fury Convertible           |        https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-424629/1965-plymouth-sport-fury-convertible/        | $13,750  |
|          1970 Plymouth Road Runner Convertible           |       https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-428253/1970-plymouth-road-runner-convertible/        | $45,000  |
|           1970 Plymouth Barracuda Convertible            |        https://www.mecum.com/lots/AZ0320-428658/1970-plymouth-barracuda-convertible/         | $42,900  |
|                 1966 Plymouth Barracuda                  |              https://www.mecum.com/lots/FL0120-394693/1966-plymouth-barracuda/               |  $9,625  |
|                 1965 Plymouth Barracuda                  |              https://www.mecum.com/lots/FL0120-394746/1965-plymouth-barracuda/               |  $7,700  |
|                 1969 Plymouth Satellite                  |              https://www.mecum.com/lots/FL0120-394747/1969-plymouth-satellite/               |  $3,850  |
|                   1954 Plymouth Savoy                    |                https://www.mecum.com/lots/FL0120-394753/1954-plymouth-savoy/                 |  $7,150  |
|                 1952 Plymouth Police Car                 |              https://www.mecum.com/lots/FL0120-394828/1952-plymouth-police-car/              |   N/A    |
|                   1970 Plymouth Duster                   |                https://www.mecum.com/lots/FL0120-394921/1970-plymouth-duster/                | $26,400  |
|                 1965 Plymouth Barracuda                  |              https://www.mecum.com/lots/FL0120-394956/1965-plymouth-barracuda/               |  $8,800  |
|               1950 Plymouth Special Deluxe               |            https://www.mecum.com/lots/FL0120-394983/1950-plymouth-special-deluxe/            |  $8,250  |
|                1973 Plymouth Road Runner                 |             https://www.mecum.com/lots/FL0120-395009/1973-plymouth-road-runner/              | $21,000  |
|                1970 Plymouth Road Runner                 |             https://www.mecum.com/lots/FL0120-395013/1970-plymouth-road-runner/              | $51,700  |
|                 1969 Plymouth Barracuda                  |              https://www.mecum.com/lots/FL0120-395106/1969-plymouth-barracuda/               | $17,600  |
|           1966 Plymouth Satellite Convertible            |        https://www.mecum.com/lots/FL0120-395145/1966-plymouth-satellite-convertible/         | $26,400  |
|                1970 Plymouth Road Runner                 |             https://www.mecum.com/lots/FL0120-395341/1970-plymouth-road-runner/              | $47,300  |
|                    1970 Plymouth Cuda                    |                 https://www.mecum.com/lots/FL0120-395362/1970-plymouth-cuda/                 | $61,000  |
|            1999 Plymouth Prowler Convertible             |         https://www.mecum.com/lots/FL0120-395647/1999-plymouth-prowler-convertible/          | $30,800  |
+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Appreciate your help! The thing is the vehicle price only appears after logging in which is why I'm using Selenium. I just don't think my while true loop is efficient enough.

Comment: @avgjoe13 let me update the answer then with the `price`, hold on

Comment: @avgjoe13 don't forget to accept the answer if it's helped you.

Comment: It's so fast! I'm really impressed actually haha. I changed your code a bit so I can append the results to a pandas df and compare it with those my while loop. The results are identical but takes a fraction of the time. I still want someone to improve my while true loop so I can learn from it. I will create a new question and be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited Ahmed's code to get my desired output (pandas df)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from prettytable import PrettyTable

data = {
    "searchScope": "past",
    "searchMake": "Plymouth",
    "searchModel": "Cuda",
    "searchYearStart": "1970",
    "searchYearEnd": "1971",
    "submit": ""
}

headers = {
    "Referer": "https://www.example.com",
}

login = {"email": "example@hotmail.com"}


price = []
urls = []
title = []
results = []


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.post(
            "https://www.example.com/includes/login-action.cfm", data=login)
        for item in range(1, 30):
            r = req.post(url.format(item), data=data, headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            target = soup.select("div.lot")
            for tar in target:
                urls.append(tar.a.get('href'))
                title.append(tar.select_one("a.lot-title").text)
                price.append(tar.span.text if tar.span.text else np.NaN)
                r = tar.select("div[class*=lot-image-container]")
                for result in results2:
                    results.append(' '.join(result2['class']))


main("https://www.example.com/search/page/{}/")


scraped_data = pd.DataFrame({'url': urls, 'year_make_model_type': title, 'price':price, 'results': results})    
scraped_data.shape

scraped_data["results"] = scraped_data["results"].str.replace("lot-image-container", "")
scraped_data["results"] = scraped_data["results"].replace('', np.NaN)
scraped_data.head()
```

Now I want to extract features from the list of product pages which are in the column 'url'. Below a working example but it's way too slow. I've tried fixing it with multiprocessing but I haven't figured it out yet. I want to extract about 10 more features for 500+ pages so it has to be faster than this.

```
low_url = ['https://www.mecum.com/lots/KC1210-101030/1970-plymouth-cuda/',
 'https://www.mecum.com/lots/SC0510-91294/1970-plymouth-hemi-cuda/',
 'https://www.mecum.com/lots/KC1210-100686/1970-plymouth-barracuda-convertible/',
 'https://www.mecum.com/lots/KA0316-235834/1970-plymouth-barracuda-convertible/',
 'https://www.mecum.com/lots/FL0110-88180/1970-plymouth-barracuda/']


reserve = []    
with requests.Session() as req:
    for url in low_url:
        r = req.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        attraction2 = []
        if not soup.find(class_=["flag flag-no-reserve"]):
            attraction2.append(np.NaN)
        else:
            r = soup.find(class_=["flag flag-no-reserve"])
            attraction2.append(r.contents[0])
        reserve.extend(attraction2)

len(reserve)
len(set(reserve))
reserve

Out: ['No Reserve', nan, nan, 'No Reserve', nan]
```

Comment: Hi @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη just wanted to thank you again for your help answering my question. I've come pretty far since then but now I'm faced with a similar problem you helped me with before. Mecum changed their environment so the answer you provided  doesn't always work anymore.. I hope you can take the time to help me out one more time! The url for the new environment is https://my.mecum.com/login and login is email: arjenvgeffen@gmail.com with password: appeltaart13. I want to search the same car as above in this environment, have tried many things without luck. Hope you can help, appreciate it!